# MYSQL inner join of two tables with non-unique columns

Tags: mysql, inner-join, alias

I have two tables (jos_table1 and jos_table2), which I want to do an inner join on element1 (from table 1) and element2 (from table2). Both tables contain a column called "parent_id" - I can't change this.

I want to count the number of rows which fulfil a certain where clause based on the parent_id element. The statement works fine if I omit the where clause, but when I have it there it doesn't work and returns the error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Does anyone know why? Any help is most appreciated.

Kind regards,

Paul Hughes

```
$table="jos_table1";
$table2= "jos_table2";

MYSQL_CONNECT($server, $user, $password) or die ( "<H3>Server unreachable</H3>");

MYSQL_SELECT_DB($database) or die ( "<H3>Database non existent</H3>");

$aiders=MYSQL_QUERY('SELECT COUNT($table.element1) AS hpp FROM $table INNER JOIN $table2 ON $table.element1=$table2.element2
WHERE `$table.parent_id` = 134
'); 

$faid = mysql_fetch_array($aiders);
$total = $faid[0];
echo "The total is (".$total.")";
```

Comment: Variables like $table are not substituted when using single quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much - worked straight away!

Answer (score 0):

The backquotes need to go around just the table part and/or just the column part.

For example:

```
WHERE `$table`.`parent_id`=134
```